Would like to link to a cell in a specific tab based on date
I have a Google workbook with tabs labeled '01', '02', '03', etc. through '12', pertinent to the month of the year.
When I execute the following formula in a Google Sheet cell, I get the desired content from that cell:
=IMPORTRANGE(A2,"07!$E$2")
A2 in the formula above is a cell that includes the url to a different workbook.
However, I would like to get the content from the cell based on the date. Thus, if it is August, I would like the content from the following cell:
=IMPORTRANGE(A2,"08!$E$2")
I tried to modify the formula to:
=IMPORTRANGE(A2,"MONTH(TODAY())!$E$2")
But, I only get: #ERROR!
Thinking that the parameter needs the leading zero for months from Jan through Sep, inclusive, I modified the formula to:
=IMPORTRANGE(A2,"TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()),"00")!$E$2")
However, I get the same error. What is my error in the formula? Thanks in advance.


You may try:
=importrange(A2,text(month(today()),"00")&"!E2")


You can do this:
=IMPORTRANGE(A2, INDIRECT("'" & TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()), "00") & "'!E2"))

Unfortunately, this gave the #REF! error.
